# Can I set rules for string comparison in SQL? (or do I need to hardcode using CASE WHEN)

Tags: sql-server, string-comparison, case-when

I need to make a comparison for ratings in two points in time and indicate if the change was upwards,downwards or stayed the same.
For example:

This would be a table with four columns:

```
 ID T0    T0+1     Status
 1  AAA   AA       Lower  
 2  BB    A        Higher   
 3  C     C        Same
```

However, this does not work when applying regular string comparison, because in SQL

```
A<B
B<BBB
```

I need

```
A>B
B<BBB
```

- So my order(highest to lowest): AAA,AA,A,BBB,BB,B
- SQL order(highest to lowest): BBB,BB,B,AAA,AA,A

Now I have 2 options in mind, but I wonder if someone know a better one:

1) Use CASE WHEN  statements for all the possibilities of ratings going up and down ( I have more values than indictaed above)

```
CASE WHEN T0=T0+1 then 'Same'
WHEN T0='AAA' and To+1<>'AAA' then 'Lower'
```

....adress all other options for rating going down

```
ELSE 'Higher'
```

However, this generates a very large number of CASE WHEN statements.

2) My other option requires generating 2 tables. In table 1 I use case when statements to assign values/rank to the ratings.
For example:

```
CASE WHEN T0='AAA' then 6
CASE WHEN T0='AA' then 5
CASE WHEN T0='A' then 4
CASE WHEN T0='BBB' then 3
CASE WHEN T0='BB' then 2
CASE WHEN T0='B' then 1
The same for T0+1.
```

Then in table 2 I use a regular compariosn between column T0 and Column T0+1 on the numeric values.

However, I am looking for a solution where I can do it in one table (with as little lines as possible), and optimally never really show the ranking column. 
I think a nested statement would be the best option, but it did now work for me.

Anybody has suggestions?

I use SQL Server 2008.

Comment: I think option 2 is better than option 1. A more compact solution would be a lookup table with columns for rating ('AAA', 'AA', 'A', and so on) and the rating's sort value. I'd especially recommend a separate table if you need this logic in other queries.

Comment: create a mapping table which has the text string and a column specifying the order they should be in. Join to that table, and order by our OrderBy column.

Comment: Yup, lookup/mapping table is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Credit Rating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credit_rating), this is very likely that this is not just about AAA > AA or BBB > BB.

Whether you are using one agency or another, it could also be AA+ or Aa1 for long term, F1+ for short term or something else in different contexts or with other agencies.

It is also often requiered to convert data from one agency to other agencies Rating.

Therefore it is better to use a mapping table such as:

```
Id | Rating
 0 |  AAA
 1 |  AA+
 2 |  AA
 3 |  AA-
 4 |  A+
 5 |  A
 6 |  A-
 7 |  BBB+
```

Using this table, you only have to join the rating in your data table with the rating in the mapping table:

```
SELECT d.Rating_T0, d.Rating_T1
    CASE WHEN d.Rating_T0 = d.Rating_T1 THEN '='
         WHEN m0.id < m1.id THEN '<'
         WHEN m0.id > m1.id THEN '>'
    END
FROM yourData d
INNER JOIN RatingMapping m0
    ON m0.Rating= d.Rating_T0
INNER JOIN RatingMapping m1
    ON m1.Rating= d.Rating_T1
```

If you only store the Rating id in you data table, you will not only save space (1 byte for tinyint versus up to 4 chars) but will also be able to compare without the JOIN to the mapping table.

```
SELECT d.Rating_Id0, d.Rating_Id1
    CASE WHEN d.Rating_Id0 = d.Rating_Id1 THEN '='
         WHEN d.Rating_Id0 < d.Rating_Id1 THEN '<'
         WHEN d.Rating_Id0 > d.Rating_Id1 THEN '>'
    END
FROM yourData d
```

The JOIN would only be requiered when you want to display the actual Rating value such as `AAA` for `Rating_ID = 0`.

You could also add an agency_Id to the Mapping table. This way, you can easily choose which Notation agency you want to display and easily convert between Agency 1 and Agency 2 or Agency 3 (ie. Id 1 => S&P and Id 2 => Fitch, Id 3 => ...)